# set multi language

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a mod_rewrite which can set the language

the rewrite:

```
www.domain.com/da/page.php => www.domain.com/page.php?set_lang=da
```

So far I have comed up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^/(da|en)/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /%2?set_lang=%1 [L]
```

but I can't figure out how you can send get vars with it too?

like this:

```
www.domain.com/da/page.php?cat=black&cow=ugly => www.domain.com/page.php?set_lang=da&cat=black&cow=ugly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yay! found a solution, but I don't know if it could be done in a better way?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^/(da|en)/(.*)(\?%{QUERY_STRING})?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /%2?set_lang=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```